# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items' python discord error

Tags: python, api, discord

Here is my code

1. Btw i am running Windows 10 Home and  i am running Python 3.8.2 with VS code
2. Any solution will do as long as it fixes my issue with Naro (My software For discord.com)
3. Btw please leave ur github link in the solution if you have one so i can credit you on my github
   4.FAQ
   5.Q- What is this software used for
   6.A- to troll people on discord
4. Q- Can i get banned
5. A- Yes because you are using a user account (Which violates TOS)

```
   import os
file = os.path.realpath(__file__)
f = open("Tokens.txt" , 'w+')
print ('Naro by hackamous')
print('1) Spam a Channel')
print('2) Spam Friend Requests')
print('3) spam DMs')
choice = input('Enter your choice:')
if choice == '1':
    server_id = input("Server id:")
    Channel_id = input("Channel id:")
    message = input('Message to spam:')
    while True:
        headers = {
            'authorization:' f"{f.readlines()}"
        }
        payload = {
            'content:' f"{message}"
        }
        total = f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{server_id}{Channel_id}'
        requests.post(f'{total}' , headers = headers , data = payload)
        exit_1 = input('Exit y/n:')
        if exit_1 == 'y':
            exit()
        else:
            continue


if choice == '2':
    name = input('Username:')
    dircrim = input('discriminator:')
    while True:
        headers = {
            'authorization:' f"{f.readlines()}"
        }
        payload = {
            'discriminator:' f"{dircrim}"
            'username:' f"{name}"
        }
        total = f'https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/relationships'
        requests.post(f'{total}' , headers = headers , data = payload)
        exit_1 = input('Exit y/n:')
        if exit_1 == 'y':
            exit()
        else:
            continue




if choice == '3':
    cha_ID = input('Channel ID:')
    msg = input('Message:')
    while True:
        headers = {
            'authorization:' f"{f.readlines()}"
        }
        payload = {
            'content:' f"{msg}"
        }
        total = f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{cha_ID}/messages'
        requests.post(f'{total}' , headers = headers , data = payload)
        exit_1 = input('Exit y/n:')
        if exit_1 == 'y':
            exit()
        else:
            continue'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the syntax you're using to construct your dicts.  For example:

```
'content:' f"{message}"
```

This not a `dict` entry, but in fact is a single concatenated string.  As a result, instead of creating a `dict`, it is creating a `set`.

In order to make it a `dict` entry, the colon needs to be outside of the string, like this:

```
'content' : f"{message}"
```

All of the dicts have this same problem, and can be fixed the same way.